# Country and region name in PHP for timezone from IP address

Tags: php, laravel-5, timezone, ip-address

I want timezones from various user logins from different locations.

For that I got IP address in Laravel 5.4 `$request->ip()`.

By using `json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ipaddr}/json"));`
I got the country and region name.

With this country and region name I will get PHP timezone name like "Europe/London"

My problem:
For some locations region name is two digit numbers in that function. But I am not getting numbers. So the timezone is null.

I am using [this](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/src/timezone.php) to obtain timezones for setting in `date_default_timezone_set();`.

Is there any other ways to get timezones?

Comment: what _do_ you get for those locations? Longitude/Latitude? Country?

Comment: Sidenote after coming across some IP related frustrations, depending on your server config, `$request->ip()` **might not** return your *client's* IP address; you'll need to look into another method to reliably retrieve that.

Comment: Also note that just because you get a country/region doesn't mean those can be created to make a valid time zone identifier.

Comment: https://ipfind.co?ip={$ipaddr} will also give you the timezone directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip}` you can also get the time zone.